# Question about exercise 6.6 from TeXbook

Tags: hyphenation

In the answer to exercise 6.6 it is said:

> TeX will try to hyphenate before `\dash`

But the folowing example shows that it will not.

```
\def\extraspace{\nobreak \hskip 0pt plus .15em\relax}
\def\dash{\unskip\extraspace---\extraspace}

\hsize=0pt
\hfuzz=10000pt
\noindent\nobreak\hskip0pt a\dash b
\bye
```

What does this phrase from answer to the exercise mean?

(Also, it seems that `\nobreak` in the second `\extraspace` does nothing. Why?)

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it means it will try to hyphenate the *word* before the dash, but in your example that word is `a` so not hyphenatable.

If you add `\showlists` you will see

```
### horizontal mode entered at line 7
\penalty 10000
\glue 0.0
\tenrm a
\penalty 10000
\glue 0.0 plus 1.49994
\tenrm | (ligature ---)
\discretionary
\penalty 10000
\glue 0.0 plus 1.49994
\tenrm b
spacefactor 1000
```

The nobreak penalty stops a break at the glue, but the break is allowed at the preceding `\discretionary` which is generated as `---` is a ligature involving the hyphenchar.